# A reference to 'C:\Solver32.DLL' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component

Tags: vba, excel, solver

Still green when it comes to programming, so bear with me. I'm currently trying to create a program in Visual Studio 2017 (VB.NET) intended to make modifications to a paired Excel spreadsheet using the Solver add-on. I've successfully created a reference for the Excel reference library but am unable to do so for the Solver reference library. I've tried creating references for both SOLVER32.DLL and SOLVER.XLAM, but both produce the same general error message:

"A reference to 'C:\xxxx.(DLL/XLAM)' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

I've browsed for hours looking for viable solutions, some of which seem to suggest repackaging the .DLL file (use of TlbImp.exe) through use of CMD and Native Tools CMD for VS (run as Admin), but that hasn't generated success (generated following error: "The input file 'C:\xxxx.DLL' is not a valid type library.") Some of the posts I've read on linking the Solver suggest the .XLAM file is specifically what needs to be used, but that hasn't generated any success, either.

I've reinstalled Microsoft Office (both x32-bit and x64-bit), reinstalled Solver multiple times, completely closed and reopened Excel with each Solver reinstall.

If it should help, I'm using an updated version of Microsoft Excel 2016 (now x64-bit) and running Windows 10 (also x64-bit, of course). The file path for Solver is MicrosoftOffice\root\Office16\Library\Solver. I've tried linking the files while Excel is open as well as when it is closed.

I've tried switching gears and using Solver Foundations instead (for which I can successfully create a reference), but there doesn't seem to be a compatible command for my project (or at least one I can wrap my head around; I'm looking for the equivalent of 'SolverOK.'

Any help here would be greatly appreciated -- starting to lose my mind over this!

Comment: As further information and an after-thought that may influence the problem, I've run into this same problem on two separate PCs but both were running Microsoft Office 365. Despite having installed the typical array of files/folders, might this be influencing the success of the Solver pairing?

Comment: Also realizing now that I've been attempting to write this using .NET despite the majority of the results giving direction for VBA.